# Communicating data between database, scene controller and stage controller

Tags: java, javafx

this is more of a concept question.

I essentially have a scene which contains a TableView at the moment with 2 columns (FirstName and LastName with object Name).

To manage this I have an observable list:

`private ObservableList<Name> _nameList = FXCollections.observableArrayList();`

The data is loaded in the table like this:

```
_nameList.addAll(_database.getNameList());
    DatabaseTable.getItems().addAll(_nameList);
    DatabaseTable.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener(((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
        _database.selectedItemTable(newValue);
    }));
```

As you can see all my data is in the database class which contains a list of Names. When a Name is selected the database receives this information through a listener.

In this scene, the user can select a Name and change the last name (This change pops up in a new Stage). When the last name is changed for the selected name, the ArrayList in the database class is updated with the corresponding Name object (where the last name is changed)

Now my trouble is how do I get the Controller for the scene and the Controller for the stage to communicate this change when the user presses confirms the change?

I want the TableView in the scene to change the Name in the cell with the updated last name

Comment: This is really hard to understand exactly what you want and what is happening instead. Please include a [mcve] in your question that demonstrates the issue.

Comment: Just making assumptions here, but as long as you are modifying the last name of the `Name` object that is contained in the `_nameList`, all you would need to do is refresh the `TableView` by calling `tableView.refresh()`. This will cause the `TableView` to basically reload the entire `_nameList`, including the new data.

Comment: It would be useful to know whether the `Name` class uses the JavaFX Property mechanisms to store data.